# Deform image along path

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've got an image I'd like to use as the border on a DVD label, which I'm creating in InDesign. The effect would be like the "Type on a path", but with an image instead - preferrably repeated until it comes to the end of the path (or full circle, in this case). How can this be achieved? I tried doing a "Polar coordinates" transform in Photoshop, but that didn't look very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Ellipse tool, draw your circle.

Click on your image with the black arrow. Copy.

Click and hold on the Type tool. In the flyout, select Type on a path.

Click on the circle.

Paste. Your image should appear on the circle as an inline graphic.

Keep pasting until you get all the way around.

Comment: For extra credit, when you get the circumference nearly filled, select all (Ctl/Cmd-A) and use InDesign's tracking control in the Character panel (the inline graphics are treated as if they were font characters) to tweak the amount of space between them so the result looks even.

Answer (score 0):

As another idea: to have almost perfectly and effotlessly achieved even spaces between your symbols, place them as Lauren suggested, but add a space before each one like that: "_s_s_s_s" (_ – space, s – symbol). Then select your "text" and in paragraph options set alignment to "justify all". Some minor kerning adjustment may be required after the first space character.